# R Syntax | Slice before variable? (e.g. (1:3) [ x ])

Tags: r

Having trouble finding information about this R syntax.  An example is:

```
> x <- 1:10
> (1:3)[ x ]
 [1]  1  2  3 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Do you know what this is called? And in what use cases it is helpful for? I am also curious about the implied operation by this syntax. Coming from python, I am not sure if there is an analogous operation with a slice/range before the variable.

Comment: See `?Extract` and [R Language Definition on vector indexing](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Indexing-by-vectors): [Assuming `x[i]`] "If `i` is positive and exceeds `length(x)` then the corresponding selection is `NA`"

Answer (score 1):

`:` isn't really "slice" in R. It's a shortcut for `seq()`. So `1:3` is the same as `seq(1,3)`. This behaves just like any other vector. So you can use `[]` to index into that vector. If you pass an index that doesn't exist in a vector, you get `NA` out. So

```
(1:3)[ x ]
```

is essentially the same as

```
c(1, 2, 3)[ c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) ]
```

You are just subsetting a vector by index. In the same way that

```
z <- c(5,10,15,20)
z[c(2,4)]
# [1] 10 20
```

returns the 2nd and 4th element.

The values you are seeing in your example are not coming from `x`. Consider

```
x <- c(1,2,3)
(100:91)[x]
# [1] 100  99  98
```

You can see that the values are not coming from `x`, but they are coming from the sequence. `x` is just used for indexing.

Comment: I think this makes sense. But in your last example, why would it not be "100, 99, 98" instead of "100, 98, 96" as shown?

Comment: @JacobAnderson Yeah. I think I copy/pasted wrong the first time. I've fixed it.